# Rails 2.3.5 model name translation problem in error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, internationalization, translation

I encountered some problem while trying to translate my model's names and attributes in a Rails 2.3.5 app.

I have the following model:

```
class BillingPlan < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :billing_option_id

  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :billing_option
end
```

When validation fails, my models attributes are translated correctly, but the modelname itself is not. I use the following translation skeleton in de.yml

```
de:
  activerecord:
    models:
      shipping_plan: "Versandart"
      billing_plan: "Rechnungsart"
    attributes:
      shipping_plan:
        shipping_option_id: "Versandoption"
      billing_plan:
        billing_option_id: "Rechnungsoption"
```

Basis for my translation file is: http://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/de.yml

Can anyone help?

Thx in advance
J.

Comment: How you call errors ? `by error_message_for` ?

Comment: Here it gets more confusing. I use formtastic for most of my forms, but have to use standard forms as well. 

In case I use formtastic like that:
<% semantic_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  ...
<% end %> everything is translated well. 

In case of standard forms:

<% form_for @billing_plan do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  ...
<% end %> I still have the problem that model names are not translated.

Answer (score 0):

try to check your translations for active record models, look at the i18n documentation, 5.1.3 section on the Rails Guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

by default rails uses this, you should create one for your de i18n:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      template:
        header:
          one:   "1 error prohibited this {{model}} from being saved"
          other: "{{count}} errors prohibited this {{model}} from being saved"
        body:    "There were problems with the following fields:"
```

Comment: oh, i see that these translations are already implemented in http://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/de.yml, perhaps my awnser didn't help much after all

Comment: Seems to be a more difficult problem. Thx anyway.